# C#: convert WAV to xWMA

Tags: c#, directx, wav, xaudio2, wma

Does anybody know how to convert a `.WAV` file to `.xWMA` in order to play it with XAudio2 in C# ?

I heard about Windows Media Format but it's not available anymore, it has been replace by Sink Writer but I can't find where to download it or how to use it.

Comment: You should be able to use xWMAEncode.exe. You can download DirectX 10 SDK from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=6812 unzip it (with 7zip for example) and it's located in DXSDK\Utilities\bin\x86 folder

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I managed to properly convert a wav file using xWMAEncode.exe, but is there a way to pass a byte array in the standardInput and get the result in the StandardOutput ? I would like to do the conversion without using the hard drive.

Comment: The tool doesn't handle that, you'll have to program the encoding yourself. xWMA is kinda deprecated and actual XAudio documentation doesn't mention it anymore so you won't find much help here. It's probable the current XAudio does still support it undercovers. The DirectX 10 SDK has a directx_sdk.chm file that explains what's xWMA format and how you can encode it

Comment: The ``xwmaencode.exe`` tool is in the [Microsoft GDK](https://github.com/microsoft/GDK).  The tool requires you do a disk file to disk file conversion as the intended use case is offline compression of audio content.